# laptop only has ubuntu, how do i delete it and install windows?

Tags: installation, partitioning

i bought a asus 1015e laptop with ubuntu as it's OS by accident. i want to delete ubuntu partition and install windows. i went to gparted and i dont know which partition to delete. also asus sells this laptop with windows as well, so i think there is a partition with windows on it already. anyway to delete ubuntu and boot into windows?
if not do i delete all partitions? thank
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPB9g.jpg

so i boot into windows setup and delete all partitions, then i cant format the HD to install windows, it says cannot install windows, the disk is of GPT partition style. please help.
if i try to boot to ubuntu it says error: no such partition grub rescue

Comment: You don't need to delete Ubuntu. Just install Windows, it will overwrite the Ubuntu installation (if you're lucky, it'll ask for permission first). Or *is* Windows already installed? I believe Asus laptops usually have one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 0):

If you have both Windows and Ubuntu installed on your computer, install GRUB: it will give you a menu whenever you boot up your computer and allow you to choose which OS to boot into each time.

Otherwise, you can just install Windows and during the install it will reformat your hard drive on its own (it deletes everything during the install)

If you are curious about the partitions currently on your computer, post any info gparted gives you about them: the number of partitions, their sizes, any identifying names or types... usually you have a main partition and a small swap partition, unless someone made it fancy, or unless you do actually have both Windows and Ubuntu installed already.

Comment: i have a picture of my gparted http://i.imgur.com/h5C9ovW.jpg?1

Comment: i have 4 partitions in the HD, maybe one of them is windows in it. anyway to merge all partition together? do i do it in ubuntu or when i install windows? thank